# If I encode a JWT and send it in a URL then surely I need the secret key to decode it?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I have this function to encode a JWT token that I send in the URL so an application.

```
encoded_token = jwt.encode({'token': token}, os.environ['SECRET_KEY'], algorithm='HS256')
```

On the application side I decode the key and then use it to get the credentials of a user. Surely if I encode a JWT token using the above function and my secret key, do I need that secret key to decode it on the application side?

At the moment that is not the case and the following function on the application side decodes the key and it's correct because I get the credentials of the user associated with the said token. So this is a security risk because I send the token in the URL (cannot seem to find another way)?

```
function decodeJwt(token) {
    var base64Payload = token.split(".")[1];
    var payload = decodeURIComponent(
        atob(base64Payload)
            .split("")
            .map(function (c) {
                return "%" + ("00" + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
            })
            .join("")
    );
    return JSON.parse(payload);
}
```

Can someone please tell me why my token is decoded without my secret key and also maybe give me another way I can send the token to the application. Help is appreciated

Comment: Your JWT isn't encrypted at all - you've merely added a digital signature, which could be used to verify the integrity of the token (but your code doesn't do this, it just throws away the signature at the receiving end).  Using the HS256 algorithm, you would indeed need the secret key at both ends to verify the signature.  You may prefer to use RS256, which uses a private key at one end, and a corresponding public key at the other end.

Comment: Thank you Jason appreciate the info. I will look into RS256

Comment: How should I send the token? Is it really the only way to send it using the URL?

Comment: Yes, you need a secret key on your server to verify your JWT token. If you want to take it one step further and enhance security, you can use RSA to generate a pair of keys - a public key and a private key. With the public key, you or anyone can encrypt data, but for decrypting it, you will need the private key